# Why my code is returning TypeError: baseURL.replace is not a function (In 'baseURL.replace(/\/+$/, '')', 'baseURL.replace' is undefined)?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, apisauce

In my React Native App, I'm using apisauce to communicate with my API and trying to get baseURL from firebase firestore. Do do this I'm using anonymous signing in to access the database. I'm getting TypeError as mentioned in question title. Please help me out.

```
import {create} from 'apisauce';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

const apiClient = create({
  method: 'POST',
  baseURL: '',
}).setBaseURL(
  async () =>
    await auth()
      .signInAnonymously()
      .then(async () => {
        console.log('success');
        await firestore()
          .collection('service_url')
          .doc('service_url')
          .get()
          .then(async document => {
            await document._data.url.toString();
          })
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      }),
);

export default apiClient;
```

Comment: I have no idea what are you trying to do. You mix async await with promises, dont actually return the data you pulled, and pass a function into setBaseUrl where im guessing it expects a string.

Comment: I just want to get the "url" filed from firestore and then set it as base url of the API client. Please tell me the correct/proper way to do this. I'm a newbie in React Native.